# Rails JSON API serializer with custom attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json-api, jsonapi-serialize

I am working on an RoR project with ruby-2.5.0 and rails 5. I am using the `jsonapi-serializers` for my API. I want to customize the attributes of the associated model. I have two models Receipt and `ReceiptPartial`. receipt `has_many :receipt_partials`. when I write `has_many :receipt_partials` in my serializer it returns all the columns but I want only a few columns.

```
class ReceiptPartialSerializer
  include JSONAPI::Serializer

  TYPE = 'receipt'
  attribute :id
  has_many :receipt_partials
end
```

I want to restrict the columns of receipt_partials.
I also tried `has_many :receipt_partials, only: ['id']` but didnot work.
How can I achieve this? Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the documentation, you should simply specify the attributes on the relevant serializer class for example if you want to display id, and name attributes in `ReceiptPartial` Serializer you could do the following.

```
class BaseSerializer
  include JSONAPI::Serializer
end

class ReceiptSerializer < BaseSerializer
  TYPE = 'receipt'
  attribute :id

  has_many : receipt_partials
end

class ReceiptPartialSerializer < BaseSerializer
  attributes :id, :name
end
```